# Auto cast to derived type without checking derived type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I have list of a type, which is a collection of different derived types. Eg:

```
A
B:A
C:A
D:A
```

So the list would have B,C,D

Now i want to iterate the list auto cast to their derived type and called the method in them.

Although this example is short, the reason i was hoping to auto cast to the derived type without checks is to avoid lengthy if/else stuff like

```
if(item[i] is B) (B).Process();
else if(item[i] is C) (C).Process();
// etc etc etc
```

This gets kinda tedious when you have a complicated setup of derived types.

Does C# have some way to auto cast to its respective `highest derived type` at all? Or am i stuck with checking each time?

Comment: Wouldn't a virtual method do this without a cast?

Comment: Wouldn't i still need to cast to the derived type to access the override method ? In this case Process is virtual in A but different in derived.

Comment: or, you can have interface with process(), and implement on all derived classes

Comment: But the interface still needs to be cast to the derived type to get its specific method behaviour no ? I'm not sure i understand how that avoids me having to cast?

Comment: I think you need to show how `Process` is implemented in the base class and one of the derived classes. Sounds like virtual is the key though

Comment: well the derived classes have `override void Process(){ }` with processing specific to that derived class data. So i presumed i have to cast to access it, or i am essentially just calling the base virutal Process method ? Or did i misunderstand.

Comment: No, you don't have to cast it, that's precisely the point of making the method virtual, you can have `List<A>`, with a virtual method, if the actual instance of an element in the list is `B` which inherits from `A`, and it overrides this virtual method, then calling `element.Process()` will call the overridden method, not the base method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using interface,

```
    internal interface IProcess
    {
        void Process();
    }
    class AA
    {
    }
    class BB : AA, IProcess
    {
        public void Process() { Console.WriteLine($"Inside: {nameof(BB)}"); }
    }
    class CC : AA, IProcess
    {
        public void Process() { Console.WriteLine($"Inside: {nameof(CC)}"); }
    }
    class DD : AA, IProcess
    {
        public void Process() { Console.WriteLine($"Inside: {nameof(DD)}"); }
    }
```

simply iterate like,

```
     var listWithInterface = new List<IProcess> { new BB(), new CC(), new DD() };
     foreach (var item in listWithInterface)
     {
           item.Process();
     }
```

*another way could be using virtual method,*

```
class A
    {
        public virtual void Process() { }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        public override void Process() { Console.WriteLine($"Inside: {nameof(B)}"); }
    }
    class C : A
    {
        public override void Process() { Console.WriteLine($"Inside: {nameof(C)}"); }
    }
    class D : A
    {
        public override void Process() { Console.WriteLine($"Inside: {nameof(D)}"); }
    }
```

and use it like,

```
var list = new List<A> { new B(), new C(), new D() };
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                item.Process();
            }
```

Comment: Oh so i don't have to cast to access the derived type's override method? Damn so i've been doing it wrong !

Comment: yes, you don't need to cast types as derived types are aware of virtual method in base type, and if virtual is overridden in derived type than calling will depend on type of object (here it is of derived type). But I personally, prefer to use interface in such conditions as it provide more flexibility and you don't have to change any signature of methods inside the classes.